# Eclipse theme in Liferay doesn't work after some lines of code

Tags: eclipse, themes, liferay

I am working with Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12.0), java jdk 1.8.0 with Liferay 7, the code theme stops working after some lines.
My friends also have the same problem with this version of Eclipse, so it's not a local thing.

I tried changing theme and resetting but this visual error doesn't seem to go away. 
[visual error of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkZ8N.png)

Edit: [other example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycGQs.png), this happens mainly in the portlets. As you can see, the variables and methods are colored in the upper part, while white in the lower part.

Comment: Since this is not a programming issue, try to ask on the eclipse forums.

Comment: @CosminStaicu Questions about programming tools are on topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Ok, sorry about that, please disregard my previous comment.

Comment: I don't understand "the code theme stops working...". I might be missing the obvious, but the question should contain a full description of expected versus actual behavior - please edit it with more of a description. Give steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: A method call with the action request is not just some lines, you need to provide more details here.